# Debug Webpack TypeScript bundles in Visual Studio 2015 and Chrome?

Tags: angular, typescript, visual-studio-2015, webpack

I am currently working on an Angular2 project, using WebPack as my build tool.

I have managed to debug my TypeScript files using Visual Studio **Code** and the Google Chrome Extension. I have also managed to get it working using Visual Studio **2015** and Internet Explorer, via the WebPack + SourceMapDevToolPlugin.

However, no matter what I try, I can't get Visual Studio 2015 and Google Chrome to work together.  The breakpoints don't get hit.  Has anyone managed to get this combination to work and if so, how did you do it?

Answer (score 0):

Debugging by setting breakpoints in VS only works when using IE, as of VS2015 Update 3. The plan is to [release support for Google Chrome in VS15](https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio/suggestions/6205061-provide-integrated-javascript-debugging-in-firefox).